# Clients can't mount NFS after power failure, NFS doesn't start

Tags: debian, nfs

I have a beowulf cluster (1 master, 2 workers) which needs an NFS in order to run the program I use. I recently refactored my cluster to be Debian 8.11 and struggled to set up the NFS as it's been a long time since I had to and had no documentation, but I got it working.

All was fine and running well until the power went out in a storm last night and upon attempting to restart the NFS and connect the workers to it, the workers would stall after attempting to

```
mount 192.168.1.99:/mnt/nfs_dir /mnt/nfs_dir
```

I tried all of

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server reload
sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server.service
sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

on the master but none of that allowed the workers to mount the NFS.

Note: While I have used Linux on and off for 5 years, I've not gone super in-depth with all of the bells and whistles despite taking a SysAdmin class 3 years ago and don't really know how to 'explore' my system and try to fix problems like this.

Comment: "... the power went out ...." Have you checked the filesystems and configuration files were not corrupted by the power failure?

Comment: What does `/etc/exports` on the NFS server look like? How about the `/etc/fstab` entry for the NFS filesystem on the workers? If you run `rpcinfo -p` on the NFS server, what is the output? If you run `rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.99` on any of the workers, does it produce the same result?

Comment: I thought there were a number of services which had to be started... rpcbind, rpc-statd, nfs-idmapd,  nfs-mountd.

Comment: @telcoM ```/etc/exports``` has a single uncommented line with the NFS mount point and other info. ```/etc/fstab``` on the workers both have the NFS info about ```192.168.1.99```


Running ```rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.99``` on the workers yields **rpcinfo: can't contact portmapper: RPC: Remote system error - Connection refused**

Comment: @C.M. when I checked the various files (```/etc/default/nfs-common```, ```/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server```), I was able to read them in nano and they were all the same as when I got the NFS running

||
||
@Bib I restarted all the services with ```nfs``` I found in my history but that didn't solve the problem

Comment: _If_ it is corruption, it is more likely likely at the filesystem level, in the inodes--the system updates he "last access time"  far more frequently then anything updates the file data/contents. I.E., check file modes (permissions), and such. Mind you, all this is _very unlikely_, but everything you can do to eliminate and narrow down the possible problem helps.